# Capture live video from a DSLR in C++/OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, video, camera, video-capture

My C++/OpenCV app runs well when I use a USB webcam to capture live video stream.

However, when I connect a Canon 5Dii with live video it doesn't find the camera.

The Canon utility captures the video well.

Should I use the VideoCapture cap(1)?

Comment: which OS? If Windows: please try VideoInput Library and the test tool: http://www.muonics.net/school/spring05/videoInput/

Comment: broke out onto separate lines and minor wording

Answer (score 0):

You should use the official [Canon Digital Camera SDK](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/standard_display/sdk_homepage) to grab frames from 5D II. There are some sample apps for connecting to the camera (as a source device) from your PC and then receiving camera events/images. Keep in mind that you need to sign up and be approved by Canon to use the SDK.

Comment: I signed up. Let's wait and see.. Thanks